# Special character in varchar in SQL

Tags: sql

I am inserting text from a file into a table, few of the lines have words like "you'll" or "don't". When I insert these lines as varchar in my table, I get an error saying - near "ll": syntax error. How do I overcome this?

Comment: You mean, skip the line? If yes, that is not an option. I have to enter every line.

Comment: No, "escape" as in add escape characters to the string so you can pass them as query arguments. E.g. `I'll` becomes `I\'ll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for responses, since I was using sqlite3, there are inbuilt string formating functions available with the library, so I was able to use sqlite3_mprintf with %q instead of %s and it took care of single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Your single quote is being considered as the end of your string.  Escape the quote that exists within your string to avoid this problem.

Comment: I am suppose to keep the lines intact.

Comment: Escape does not mean skip, it means to add a special character to tell the computer something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your SQL statement.  If you are using SQL Server, then you can use [`QUOTENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use two apostrophes within apostrophe-quoted strings to insert the apostrophe:

```
insert into footable (foo) values('you''ll')
```